# Using .htaccess rewrite rule that doesn't run for specific folders and files

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create a *.htaccess* file that reads `index/somepage` as `index.php?q=somepage`.
This is how far I got:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

But this still breaks all the css/img/js/etc, where is my mistake?

Comment: Rewrite conditions only apply to the *next* rewrite rule.   Maybe you need to copy the rewrite conditions for your second rewrite rule as well?

Comment: As Stephen says, except you don't want the _same_ conditions for the second rule. In fact it doesn't look like you should be using the `OR` flag at all?